# documents remove themselves unexpectedly mongoid rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, mongoid

I don't really know how to describe why it happens, or how to reproduce it. I have a method that downloads some data from an external site, and saves it to a document. If i look for the document later (ex: via find) it's gone.

If i'm in the console and i have the object assigned to a variable before hand, i can access the data via that variable, but .find won't find it, and the Collection.count is one fewer.

Why would this this happen? Any ideas?

This is hosted on heroku using mongolab. I was thinking maybe the database is running out of space, but the stats page seems to indicate otherwise.

Am I reading it wrong? Here is the db.stats() output:

```
{
  "serverUsed": "A_URL_HERE",
  "db": "DB_NAME_HERE",
  "collections": 11,
  "objects": 116295,
  "avgObjSize": 3300.993611075283,
  "dataSize": 383889052,
  "storageSize": 474427392,
  "numExtents": 49,
  "indexes": 9,
  "indexSize": 4259696,
  "fileSize": 520093696,
  "nsSizeMB": 16,
  "ok": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a lot of different problems, but the most likely is that you've hit quota. You can see an explanation for each of the different storage stats in the MongoLab UI. The fact that storageSize and fileSize are near quota mean you're close if you're not hitting it.

No matter the source of the problem you should make sure you're using safe mode. It's the default when using the new [MongoClient method of creating connections](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/36666163412/introducing-mongoclient) through your driver. It will check for errors before moving one, whereas in the past that was not the default behavior. There's a good chance the server is returning an error (which it will do when you hit quota) but the driver isn't checking for it.

As always, you can write us directly at support@mongolab.com and we'd be more than happy to help!

Comment: is there a way to retroactively turn it into a capped collection so that newer documents push out older documents?

Comment: Yes, according to [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) you can run `db.runCommand({"convertToCapped": "mycoll", size: 100000});` where size is in bytes.